# How to have calculated properties on state?

Tags: rxjs, ngxs

Using NGXS, I have state in my project. I use a service to load some data into state. All works well. However, I also need to expose a property which takes data from another property on state and transforms it. I want to use .pipe to ensure that transformed data stays in sync with actual data. I just can't figure out where to put this transformation logic.

Comment: I would include that prop in your state tree and use a reducer to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `@Selector` to project a derived property based on your state model, e.g:

```
export interface MyStateModel {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@State<MyStateModel>()
export class MyState {

  // Selector to project derived 'fullName' property of the state.
  @Selector()
  static fullName(state: MyStateModel): string { 
     return state.firstName + ' ' + state.lastName;
  }

  // Load the data 
  @Action(LoadData)
  loadData({patchState}: StateContext<MyStateModel>) { 
     patchState({
       firstName: 'Joe',
       lastName: 'Bloggs',
     }
  }

}
```

Then in your component use to that Selector directly:

```
@Select(MyState.fullName) fullName$: Observable<string>;
```